# Create events with a secondary calendar by default

Tags: google-calendar

When I want to create an event, I usually want to do it with a secondary calendar, so I have to click on the combo-box to change the calendar as follows:

[image: screenshot]

How could I set another calendar as the default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to set a secondary calendar as the default selection in Google Calendar.

Here are two workarounds which could perhaps make your life easier.

#### Workaround 1: Using keyboard shortcuts

In your screenshot, you have selected the area from 00:00 to 02:30 with your mouse. Now, the cursor is in the "What"-field.

1. Type the event name
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select the calendar drop-down menu
3. <kbd>c</kbd> to select the calendar called "carlos helder" (first letter of the calendar)
4. <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select the "Create event"-button
5. <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the event

Not the optimal solution, but at least <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> is most of the time faster than using the mouse.

#### Workaround 2: Using a client calendar application

Perhaps you can connect your Google Calendar account to some client calendar application which provides the option to select a secondary calendar as the default calendar for events.

For iOS there is a paid app called [Week Calendar](http://weekcal.com) which is pretty awesome and allows to [select a default calendar](https://weekcalendar.zendesk.com/entries/23280573-Default-Calendar) or allows you to create template events.

[image]

[Source](http://isource.com/2010/09/17/review-week-calendar-for-iphone/).

For OS X the default Calendar application provides the option to select a default calendar.

[image]

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202337).

Of course, this is no solution if you prefer to use the Google Calendar web interface.